# Why my python client hangs when recieving data from internet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sockets, networking

I'm trying to make a simple port scanner using python but it seems that it hangs during`recv` that the default timeout raise an exception and terminate the program.

```
import socket, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A Port scanner",
                                 usage="command -w <website> -p <port>",
                                 prog="Port Scanner")

parser.add_argument("-w", nargs=1, type=str, required=True, dest="site",
                    help="The website to scan")
parser.add_argument("-p", nargs=1, type=int, dest="port",
                    help="The port to scan", default=80)

namespace = parser.parse_args()
def connect(host: str, port:int) -> bool:
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
    conn_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        conn_sock.connect((ip, port))
    except:
        print("[+] port {} is closed".format(port))
        return False
    else:
        print("[+] Port {} is open".format(port))
        conn_sock.sendall(b"HTTP GET /")
        response = conn_sock.recv(100)
        print("[+] Got 100 bytes as {}".format(response))
        return True
connect(namespace.site[0], namespace.port[0])
```

running as `prog -w www.google.com -p 80`(also tried with different websites) it says that port 80 is opened and connected as supposed also sending data doesn't seem to cause any problem. Trackback is

```
    response = conn_sock.recv(100)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: I'm sure that you have a good reason to use low-level sockets to perform HTTP requests rather than using `urllib` or `requests`? Just thought I'd make sure :)

Comment: conn_sock.sendall(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is not responding because you have not sent it a complete or valid request. Try:

```
conn_sock.sendall(b"HTTP GET /\r\n\r\n")
```

A blank line is required between the (optional) headers and the (optional) body. You don't set any headers so you simply need two CRLFs at the end of the request. This will get you communicating with the server.

But you should change your request to:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

if you want to get a valid `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response.